# I need to catch one value each minute to do my calculation in vba (Visual Basic)

Tags: vba

As you can see below, I need to catch one value each minute to do my calculation in Visual Basic.

LEF_F - Current Value of Efficiency and after 1 minute LEF_F need to be transferred to LEF_LM that is the value measured in the last minute and LEF_F updates his value.

Please, could you help me with this issue?

I am sending below my draft calculation without the calculus mentioned above.

```
"macro_command main()

short a, Reset, Counter, Speed, LEF_F, LEF_LM, Sum, Time

GetData(a, "Local HMI", "LEF_C", 1)

GetData(Reset, "KHS - Filler", "DB_Data_MainPLC_To_Ferru.fResetProductionHours", 1) 
// Need to confirm reset bit with KHS

GetData(Counter, "KHS - Filler", "CcPLCInnofill.Tag0692", 1)

GetData(Speed, "KHS - Filler", "CcPLCInnofill.Tag0254", 1)

GetData(Time, "KHS - Filler", "CcPLCInnofill.Tag0694", 1)

if Reset >= 1 then
LEF_F == 100
else if Reset == 0 then
LEF_F = a
else
end if

LEF_LM = LEF_F * (Time/(Time - 1))
// In case of Time is in minutes use "1" other way need to verify which unit Time is using

Sum = (LEF_F + LEF_LM)/2

SetData(Sum, "Local HMI", "EFF_Line", 1)

end macro_command"
```

Thanks a lot for your help and support.

Best regards,

Thiago Moraes dos Santos

Comment: Doesn't look like VBA - do you mean VB.Net?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub DoWork()

    '"macro_command main()

    Dim a, Reset, Counter, Speed, LEF_F, LEF_LM, Sum, Time As Short

    GetData(a, "Local HMI", "LEF_C", 1)
    GetData(Reset, "KHS - Filler", "DB_Data_MainPLC_To_Ferru.fResetProductionHours", 1)

    ' Need to confirm reset bit with KHS
    GetData(Counter, "KHS - Filler", "CcPLCInnofill.Tag0692", 1)
    GetData(Speed, "KHS - Filler", "CcPLCInnofill.Tag0254", 1)
    GetData(Time, "KHS - Filler", "CcPLCInnofill.Tag0694", 1)

    If Reset >= 1 Then
        LEF_F = 100
    ElseIf Reset = 0 Then
        LEF_F = a
    Else

    End If

    LEF_LM = LEF_F * (Time / (Time - 1))
    ' In case of Time is in minutes use "1" other way need to verify which unit Time is using

    Sum = (LEF_F + LEF_LM) / 2

    SetData(Sum, "Local HMI", "EFF_Line", 1)

    'end macro_command"

End Sub
```